# How to make other language string in Android?

Tags: android

I want to make my native language version Android app. Like below, some string will be shown via the Toast. The string "备份失败!" means "Backup failed!".

```
Toast.makeText(ReadLog.this, "备份失败!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Above one is hard coded, and I will change it to English when I need an English version.
Do we have better method?

Comment: I'd _really_ recommend starting by reading [this developer page on Android localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) which describes how to do what you're asking, and coming back if you have further questions :)

Comment: Use google translate API

Answer (score 0):

You can difine you text in string.xml files in res folder

[Check for your reference](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

Hope this helps

Later, you can use

```
// Get a string resource from your app's Resources
String hello = getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create different strings.xml files for different languages.

Read [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Answer (score 0):

create another values folder likes values-zh-rCN, put a string.xml which contain your Chinese string values